# Moving JButtons

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

What would be the best way for me to move the buttons so they are under each other instead of beside each other (see image below)?

[image]

The code for this class is as follows.  The Main method is in a different class.

```
package guiplay;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;



public class MainGUI extends JFrame {

  private JButton openReportSelection = new JButton("Open Report Viewer");
  private JButton closeButton = new JButton("Close Program");



    private JButton getCloseButton(){
        return closeButton;
    }   
    private JButton getOpenReportSelection(){
        return openReportSelection;
}

    public MainGUI(){
        mainInterface(); 
    }

    private void mainInterface(){          
        setTitle("Program Information Application");   
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());        
        centerPanel.add(openReportSelection);
        openReportSelection.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                JFrame reports = new JFrame();
                new ReportGUI();
            }
        });  
        centerPanel.add(closeButton);       
        getCloseButton().addActionListener(new Listener());
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        setSize(700,200);
        setVisible(true);            
    }




}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `BoxLayout` as it aligns all elements either horizontally or vertically. Simply set `BoxLayout`'s axis to `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS`.

[image: BoxLayout with axis set to BoxLayout.Y_AXIS]

Example:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;

public class BoxLayoutExample extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel contentPane;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    BoxLayoutExample frame = new BoxLayoutExample();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public BoxLayoutExample() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 180, 150);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new BoxLayout(contentPane, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

        JButton btnOpenReportViewer = new JButton("Open Report Viewer");
        contentPane.add(btnOpenReportViewer);

        JButton btnCloseProgram = new JButton("Close Program");
        contentPane.add(btnCloseProgram);
    }

}
```

If you want to control the size so that they are similar to each other, you can use a grid layout by setting the `JFrame`'s content pane to a `GridLayout`:

```
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1, 0, 0)); // the value of 1 here means 1 column
```

[image: GridLayout with buttons that are the same size]

Answer (score 4):

Don't put the JButtons in a container that uses FlowLayout but rather one that uses another layout that allows stacking of components. A GridLayout comes to mind if the buttons are to be the same size, or if they need to be different sizes, a BoxLayout.

Check out [the Layout Manager Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

You could try using a BoxLayout instead of a FlowLayout. In that case, you could have:

```
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new BoxLayout());  
centerPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(centerPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS)); // Y_AXIS will cause the components to be added vertically
centerPanel.add(openReportSelection);
centerPanel.add(closeButton);
centerPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 60)); // Set the maximum horizontal and vertical distances used, as BoxLayouts expand to fill the provided area
```

Or as Hovercraft said, you could use a GridLayout, in which case you would specify it as follows:

```
JPanel centerPanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,0); // The "0" parameter specifies as many rows as needed, but only one column
centerPanel.add(openReportSelection);
centerPanel.add(closeButton);
centerPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(100, 60)); // GridLayouts will also expand to fill the entire area, so you'll probably want some size parameters.
```

You could also see [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) for more on BoxLayouts, or [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/grid.html) for more on GridLayouts.